# Best Tools for 2D Constructive Area Geometry

Tags: java, c, apache-flex, geometry

What are the best tools/libraries (in any language) for working with 2D constructive area geometry?

That is, a library working with more or less arbitrary two dimensional shapes and supplying union, intersection, difference and XOR.

My baseline is the [java.awt.geom.Area](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class, and that's serviceable if slow.  What's out there that's better?  My particular interests are Java, ActionScript/Flex, and C libraries, but I'm open to any comers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come in mind

1. [Cairo Graphics](http://www.cairographics.org/)  for C
2. [Antigrain](http://www.antigrain.com/) for C++

I propose Cairo.
It is

- Mature
- Tested (used internally in GTK+ and Mozilla)
- supported (great community mailing list, irc, web e.t.c)
- Open Source

Cairo has already the operators you mention (union, intersection, difference e.t.c)
and using paths you can draw any shape you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

The [Computational Geometry Algorithms Library](http://www.cgal.org/) is quite extensive. It had a commercial and an open source license last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the windows world you may consider using MFC which has CRgn and other ops that you can use to compute those differences- most notably it is easy to create splines that clip regions- and then you can easily work with those clipped regions (areas, intersections, etc).

I assume since the MFC operations are encapsulating GDI- you could use GDI directly to do the same ops, but of course if you have and don't mind MFC then it is worth checking out.